# How to type-guard a sub-type?

Tags: typescript, types

In the following example, I believed I was guarding the `mainType` properly with `'b' in mainType.a`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
type MainType<Sub extends SubType> = { a: Sub, b: string  }
type SubType = Sub1 | Sub2
type Sub1 = { a: string }
type Sub2 = { a: string, b: string }

function handle<Sub extends SubType>(mainType: MainType<Sub>) {
  if ('b' in mainType.a) {
    handle1(mainType);
  }
}

function handle1(a: MainType<Sub2>) {
}
```

How do I make `handle1` accept the type without type assertion?

[Here's a Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQwJYDsAqkoB4DKBXAIxigA8QoUATAZxnwI2gD4YBeGAbxgQC47CANDAJ9qIAE6oA5jBgBfUJn4Ml7egEYYAH2UAmRdGWb2XXjDGSUMheEP1dbTt1ETpQkeddX5wYADM8FABjECQAexQYAAsEKgAbbHpiMgoaZUYoJgAKAFtkdEw+RFQM3EImAEpOYFkkPxgsgHICRphUGDySzAA6BCqOGtlo2MoE9Vz8jIqAbkGFBQDg0Ijh+Khxs2KC6DKCXUrqhSA)

Comment: You can extract to custom type guard.

Comment: @AlekseyL. can you illustrate?

Comment: Not sure if that helps [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQwJYDsAqkoB4DKBXAIxigA8QoUATAZxnwI2gD4YBeGAbxgQC47CANDAJ9qIAE6oA5jBgBfUJn4Ml7egEYYAH2UAmRdGWb2XXjDGSUMheEP1dbTt1ETpQkeddX5wYADM8FABjECQAexQYAAsEKgAbbHpiMgoaZUYoJgAKAFtkdEw+RFQM3EImAEpOYFkkPxgspGp7XPyMiqqOGtlo2MoE9VaSzAqAbm6FBX9AkPDIppa-MLCitswylWYKviWwmCb4NegN3RYu2XEoEDxxSIByAjv9yN2AOgRxqYDg0Ije+KggzMxQKx3slWqCiAA)

Comment: Could you describe a real use case? Just curious

Comment: @AlekseyL. don't you agree that that custom type guard is still a type assertion, but with extra steps? I'd rather have the compiler do its thing, it has all the information. [This is closer to the use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59611715/592641). I'm creating an abstraction over DynamoDB.

Comment: The compiler may have all the information but it doesn't have all the processing time to use it; only discriminated unions are automatically narrowed when their (discriminant) property is checked.  In your case, `mainType` is not of a discriminated union type (it's not even of a union type... `{a: 0 | 1}` has a union property but is not a union itself), and therefore checking `mainType.a` does not narrow `mainType`.  User-defined type guards and/or type assertions might be the best we can do here.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995 might also be related.