# Guarded type, still not assignable

Tags: typescript, types

My out type depends on the input type. I'm guarding the input with custom guard, but it's still not assignable to declared output:

```
type InputType<Sub extends SubType> = { a: Sub, b: string }
type SubType = Sub1 | Sub2
type Sub1 = { a: string }
type Sub2 = { a: string, b: string }
type OutputType<Sub extends SubType> =
  Sub extends Sub2 ?
    { c: string, d: string } :
    { c: string }

function handle<Sub extends SubType>(mainType: InputType<Sub>): OutputType<Sub> {
  if (hasSub2(mainType)) {
    return {c: '', d: ''};
  } else {
    return {c: ''};
  }
}

function hasSub2(a: InputType<SubType>): a is InputType<Sub2> {
  return 'b' in a.a;
}
```

[Here's a Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuCAeAyogRlCAD2AjgBMBnKHXNSAPigF4oBvKAQwC5q8AaKLh4VgAJwCWcAOZQAvgChQkXrXTMVARigAfFQCZFamlpbtuUEROlzDymnvVnhYyVIFCLL6wqXQA8shIqOjYeATEpJQqdBCMTPJQKuEk5FT2UAD8CYlsUADGzlZuUGSFrnJQXNmJ7AWeRTbyAGaIcHnA4gD2cFAAFhzkADaYNMmRaXgx9AAUALYckjE88EExobj0AJQ8AcCrITSMrNniTVDT-RT2cwtwMZubbNVQohDAiKI9rHUA5D8CpSgf1kAG5srICIMKNBjjkXm8Pl9fj9QeD5Apmq12l0epdruYVsg1jQpttOFBxFRCcFIOs9Edsq93p8gbgfhSehwAHQcMEKIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A current TS design limitation is that function return expressions must be assignable to the explicit unresolved conditional return type annotation, narrowing with the control flow  doesn't help ([issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)).

`{c: '', d: ''}` and `{c: ''}` in `handle` are not assignable to the unresolved conditional return type `OutputType<Sub>`. You can do the following:

1. cast all return expressions to `OutputType<Sub>` ([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuCAeAyogRlCAD2AjgBMBnKHXNSAPigF4oBvKAQwC5q8AaKLh4VgAJwCWcAOZQAvgFgAUKEi9a6ZmoCMUAD5qATEpXQaOlu25QRE6XOMaaBzZeFjJUgUOvu7C5RoA8shIqOjYeATEpJRqdBCMTEpQalEk5FROUAD8ySlsUADGbraeUGQlHnJQXHkp7MU+pfaKSgBmiHCFwOIA9nBQABYc5AA2mDRpMZl48fQAFAC2HJLxPPCh8RG49ACUPMHAm+E0jKx54m1Q88MUTksrcPG7u2x1UKIQwIiiA6yNAHIAQIKlAgbJOFRDsdINt6ABuPIQiCjCjQc6KfIfL4-P6AgEQjhQkLILanRGYlr+dqdbp9Aa3e5WDakk6zdB7HgcKDiKgssKwpxnPKfb6-MG4AE8gYcAB0HAp-iAA))
2. create a separate function overload ([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuCAeAyogRlCAD2AjgBMBnKHXNSAPigF4oBvKAQwC5q8AaKLh4VgAJwCWcAOZQAvgFgAUKEi9a6ZmoCMUAD5qATEpXQaOlu25QRE6XOMaaBzZeFjJUgUOvu7C5RoA8shIqOjYeATEpJRqdBCMTEpQalEk5FROUAD8yWxQAMZutp5QZMUeclBceexFPiX2ikoAZohwBcDiAPZwUAAWHOQANpg0aTGZePH0ABQAthyS8TzwofERuPQAlDzBwOvhNPSt7Z09fYMjEAtLcCuwCMgbNDO7UPuHkJszbHniLSgswA5LhgVBJFBFst0AA6DjbP6KFIpUQQYCIUR9Oo8YHAgTlKB4uQAbjysgIwwo0FYeVR6Mx2MKuPBsjJyKa-iUBV6ImseC0ACUIFQWFcyKNZq58lYAEQcDiyuReHiy3BK2SIgD0WrY9RsHhJTR5cD5FDwBmFooGQwlN2l0vlipVUHl6uVglV7s1UB1+X1vikRsJBukRtkQA))

#### Implementation of alternative 2

```
function handle<Sub extends SubType>(mainType: InputType<Sub>): OutputType<Sub>
function handle(mainType: InputType<SubType>): OutputType<SubType> {
  if ('b' in mainType.a) {
    return { c: '', d: '' };
  } else {
    return { c: '' };
  }
}

const sub1Res = handle({ a: { a: "aa" }, b: "b" }) // {c: string; }
const sub2Res = handle({ a: { a: "aa", b: "ab" }, b: "b" }) // { c: string; d: string; }
```

This way, the caller of the function gets the right return type and also the body of the function (callee or implementation side) compiles now.

Comment: Please, when you can, explain a bit how the heck does the overload work. If I change order of the overload, it's unassignable again. If I just leave the `OutputType<SubType>`, it infers all variants in the return type (obviously). So I can't wrap my mind around why would this exact order yield the desired behavior.

Comment: Sure, there is only one overload here (the first line), the other is the function implementation. The overload signatures are for the callers, the function impl. signature must be sufficient as a base type for all overload variants. `OutputType<SubType>` is a base type of `OutputType<Sub>`, so that is already fine. The advantage is, that we have eliminated the unresolved conditional type with this implementation signature (`SubType` is just a union `Sub1 | Sub2`), so `{ c: '', d: '' }` or `{ c: '' }` are both assignable. The call side still benefits of conditional type in the overload.